# ETL issue with stream from oracle to DB2

Tags: oracle, db2

i have an ETL in Oracle that transform the data and send them with INSERT INTO on a database DB2. For the tables that have few rows there aren't problem, but for two tables that it have 400000 rows, there are problem.

1. The insert operation is very slow, in average 50/60 rows for second. And i suspect that in DB2 there is the auto-commit for each row.
2. when the last loop ends, the procedure continues execution for infinity time. If i terminate the execution , all the rows are written correctly in DB2 DB. Then, if i try to lounch a select on the Db2 from oracle, SQL Dev it tell me that the connection is closed.

I'm Sorry for my english, i hope that you help me.

```
DECLARE
  V_MIN                NUMBER := 1;
  V_MAX                NUMBER := 40000;
  ....
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM DB2C.TABLE_DEST@RELMANAG;
    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
  END;

 SELECT COUNT(*)
 INTO V_CONT_ORCL_FS
 FROM TABLE_ORIGIN;

 WHILE V_MIN <= v_cont_orcl_fs  LOOP
   FOR I IN
  (query_Cursor on TABLE_ORIGIN    )
  LOOP
    insert into ....
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    END;
  END LOOP; --FOR
  V_MIN  := V_MAX + 1;
  V_MAX := V_MAX + 40000;


 END LOOP; --WHILE
 COMMIT;
END;
```

I can try with COPY on SQL*PLUS but not work

Comment: Can you show us the relevant SQL you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert lots of rows into a DB2-database, you can use the [load command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-78).

This command loads the data from a CSV-file into the database and is exactly what you need in this situation. However, you need to export the data in the appropriate format from your Oracle database first.

Comment: Hi Uooo, thanks for your reply, but i don't have controll on DB2, i have a DB-Link from Oracle to DB2 and i can only write and read the data. But 
I propose it to my boss as a last possible solution.